# How to update the Listview Grouping when other listview items are deleted in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grouping

I have been stuck when listview grouping item template list values are not updated when other listview values are removed in xamarin forms.

```
identifiedItems.Lists = new List<IdentifiedListItems>();
IdentifiedListItems identifiedListItems = new IdentifiedListItems();


identifiedListItems.TotalIncTax = "123"
identifiedListItems.TotalLabourTime = "12hrs"
identifiedItems.Lists.Add(identifiedListItems);
var group = new ListViewGrouping<IdentifiedItems, IdentifiedListItems>(identifiedItems, identifiedItems.Lists);
SuperServiceIdentifiedItemsModel.IdentifiedItem.Add(group);



public ICommand RemoveItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new FreshCommand(async (obj) =>
        {
                    
} });
```

When i was remove how to update the listview group items.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: none of that code is especially relevant.  It doesn't show how any of your models are defined or what you are actually doing to remove something from the list.  Are you using `ObservableCollection` for your models?  The UI should update automatically when adding or removing from an OC.